# How to check text field presence Xcode (programmatically coded)

Tags: swift, xcode, button, textfield

I am currently stuck with an issue which I can't seem to get round with linking a text box to a presence check function.

I have hard coded the text box and interface instead of using the storyboard interface Xcode gives to further my skills, but I am stuck with how to get around this. The function to set up the GUI in the ViewDidLoad for the button and text field is:

```
        //making the Email text equal to the custom Hoshi Text Field - PasswordText field is the same 
    let EmailAddressText = HoshiTextField()
    //setting the text field to not have auto constraints put in, so that constraints can be put in later
    EmailAddressText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //setting the placeholder text colour to black
    EmailAddressText.placeholderColor = .black
    //setting the placeholder text to be equal to Email Address
    EmailAddressText.placeholder = "Email Address"
    //setting the border active and inactive colour
    EmailAddressText.borderActiveColor = .systemGreen
    EmailAddressText.borderInactiveColor = .systemGray5
    //setting the delegate
    EmailAddressText.delegate = self
    //adding the text box to the temporary view
    view.addSubview(EmailAddressText)

//adding in the Login Button
    let LoginButton = UIButton()
    //setting the Button to not have auto constraints put in, so that constraints can be put in later
    LoginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //setting the title for the button when it is in the normal condition
    LoginButton.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
    //setting the colour for the button
    LoginButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    //set the background colour so it stands out from the background
    LoginButton.backgroundColor = .black
    //setting it to have round corners
    LoginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    //adding the button to the temp view
    view.addSubview(LoginButton)
   //setting the function which will be called when the button is pressed
    LoginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    //setting the view with the label and constraints to the original view
    self.view = view
```

The constraints are done using the NSConstraint.active feature, and the code for the function loginPressed() is:

```
    //setting the login pressed function
@objc private func loginPressed() {
    
    guard let Email = EmailAddressText.text, EmailAddressText.text?.count != 0 else {
        AlertService.showAlert(style: .alert, title: "Error", message: "Please enter a valid email address and try again")
        return
    }
    
    guard let Password = PasswordText.text, PasswordText.text?.count != 0 else {
        AlertService.showAlert(style: .alert, title: "Error", message: "Please enter the correct password and try again")
        return
    }
    
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: Email, password: Password) { (data, err) in
        if let err = err {
            AlertService.showAlert(style: .alert, title: "Login error", message: "Error code: \(err.localizedDescription) Please try again later")
        } else {
            //login success
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "LoginBool")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginSuccess", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

The variable names are from when the text boxes were connected through the Interface Builder, but they are the same in the hard coded version, though the function cannot access the text fields, which I can't seem to find a way around.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please further explain what you mean with _"the function cannot access the text fields"_.

Comment: I meant that the function which would be called when the button is pressed (loginPressed) cannot find the text fields (EmailAddress and PasswordText), so at the moment it cannot find any text fields to do presence checks on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is declare your text field outside of the method it currently is, which I assume would be your `viewDidLoad()`.  Currently your text field and button are only directly accessible in the scope of the method they're created in, by moving the declaration of your text field to your controller class, you can then access the text field directly from anywhere in the controller.  Also, the Swift recommended naming convention for an instance of an object, a text field for instance, is camel cased starting with a lower case, i.e. `emailAddressText` instead of `EmailAddressText`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let emailAddressText = HoshiTextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //setting the text field to not have auto constraints put in, so that constraints can be put in later
        emailAddressText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //setting the placeholder text colour to black
        emailAddressText.placeholderColor = .black
        //setting the placeholder text to be equal to Email Address
        emailAddressText.placeholder = "Email Address"
        //setting the border active and inactive colour
        emailAddressText.borderActiveColor = .systemGreen
        emailAddressText.borderInactiveColor = .systemGray5
        //setting the delegate
        emailAddressText.delegate = self
        //adding the text box to the temporary view
        view.addSubview(emailAddressText)
        // rest of your code
        // ...
        // ...
    }

    @objc private func loginPressed() {
        // small tip: A variable created in a guard statement can be used later in the same guard statment
        guard let email = emailAddressText.text, email.count != 0 else {
            return
        }
        print("Email: \(email)")
    }
}
```